# "That's my jam" - is it only for songs?

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang

What does "That's my jam" I heard this phrase in TV serial 'Scream Queens' and the woman who said this dialogue was referring to some song.

I searched it on Internet and found out from some local sites that it means that the song which was being played was one of the favorite song of the speaker.  I just want to make sure that is this information correct and can we say 'that's my jam 'to refer to some other things other than songs or this phrase is just for referring song.

Comment: As Jake Roper says: JAM, Just Awesome Music!

Answer (score 10):

It originally refered to favourite music in someone's personal playlist or music collection, and more specifically to music that forms a 'soundtrack' to their life or activities.

It has come to be applied more generally to refer to something that the person likes a lot, approves of strongly or enjoys doing. Examples could include:

- 'Grilling steaks in the backyard with friends, yeah that's my jam!'
- 'like my girls a little plump, yeah, curvy is my jam'
- 'Bass pounding dance music, that EDM stuff is my jam'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you use: "That's my jam" when referring to one of your favorite songs.

But it isn't really used outside of music. Mostly because ***jamming*** refers to the musicians having fun and playing well. And it's become a slang word describing the listener to be having fun or being very into the music.

Comment: I don't even know if "That's my jam" is commonly used when referring to music. (It may be gaining traction, but I don't think I've heard anyone say it.) I think a more common way to say it is, "I love this song!"

Comment: Yes I would agree, I would personally use 'I love that song' But I think that some would use 'that's my jam'. I was just explaining why someone would use that **if** they used that. @J.R.

Comment: I don't think there's a good basis for this. I've heard "that's my jam" to refer to all sorts of things that have nothing to do with music. Its root is in music, but I think it's spread beyond that already.

Comment: Mmm.. Pepperoni AND mushroom?! Thats my jam!

Comment: I agree with @Epicedion. It originated in music, but like many phrases, it has spread to other areas.

Answer (score 1):

A former coworker who stopped working for our mutual employer told me that the job, "just wasn't her jam." She just could not get interested or excited about the position and did not feel she was a good fit -- very important for a jam amongst musicians and for someone working in a small office such as ours.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "That's my jam" refers to a song. (Example: Is that Enter Sandman playing? That's my jam!") To use it in a way that describes something other than music, is just wrong, wrong, wrong. Stop it, please!